# Empty Unity project generates "Access Violation (0xc0000005)" error

Tags: unity-game-engine, crash

I have been working on a game for the past few months. In the editor everything is fine.
When I built the game, everything was still fine, but when I launched the build, I got an "Access Violation (0xc0000005)" error.

After looking on forums, I found that while this error seems very common, it also seems that dozens of causes can trigger this error.

After spending a couple of days to narrow down the source of the problem, I ended up creating a new project, building it without any modification (empty project) and launching it.
I obtain the exact same error!

I tried updating my OS, and the different drivers.
I tried building the game with Unity version 2017.3.1f1, and version 2017.4.0f1.
I also tried to build the game in 32bit. "Access Violation (0xc0000005)" again.

Here is my configuration:
OS: Windows 10. Most recent update.
CPU: i7-4790 3.60GHz
GPU: Asus R9 270X-DC2 TOP. Most recent driver update.

Here is the error.log:

```
Crash Test [version: Unity 2017.4.0f1 (b5bd171ee9ba)]

UnityPlayer.dll caused an Access Violation (0xc0000005)
in module UnityPlayer.dll at 0033:3b73b91f.

Error occurred at 2018-04-03_230714.
D:\Dropbox\Divers\Programmation\Unity\Tuto\Crash Test\Crash Test 64.exe, run by vdlmrc.
44% memory in use.
16315 MB physical memory [9001 MB free].
18747 MB paging file [9963 MB free].
134217728 MB user address space [134217225 MB free].
Read from location 00000020 caused an access violation.

Context:
RDI: 0xffffffff RSI: 0x00000000 RAX: 0x00000000
RBX: 0x7c5c6930 RCX: 0x00000000 RDX: 0xffffffff
RIP: 0x3b73b91f RBP: 0x908fec00 SegCs: 0x00000033
EFlags: 0x00010246 RSP: 0x908feaf8 SegSs: 0x0000002b
R8: 0x00000000 R9: 0x00000001 R10: 0x00000000
R11: 0x00000246 R12: 0x00000000 R13: 0x00000001
R14: 0x00000001 R15: 0x00000110

Bytes at CS:EIP:
41 8b 48 20 41 8b 40 18 8d 04 48 41 8b 48 24 99

Stack:
0x908feaf8: 3b7394a1 00007ff8 00000000 00000000 ..s;............
0x908feb08: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x908feb18: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x908feb28: 00000000 00000000 c85642a6 0000c4a1 .........BV..... 
0x908feb38: 3afa03f1 00007ff8 00000018 00000000 ...:............
0x908feb48: 7c5ecd50 00000226 00000000 00000000 P.^|&...........    
0x908feb58: 908fed01 000000f7 908fecf9 000000f7 ................
0x908feb68: 89c90803 00007ff8 00060ee4 00000000 ................
0x908feb78: 3b73ce90 00007ff8 00000000 00000000 ..s;............
0x908feb88: 00000110 00000000 908fecc8 000000f7 ................
0x908feb98: 3afa3553 00007ff8 7c5f9540 00000226 S5.:....@._|&...
0x908feba8: 0000218d 00000000 7c275e20 00000226 .!...... ^'|&...
0x908febb8: 3afa03f1 00007ff8 908fed01 000000f7 ...:............
0x908febc8: 3b734345 00007ff8 00000000 00000000 ECs;............
0x908febd8: 00000044 00000000 7c5f9570 00000226 D.......p._|&...
0x908febe8: 3afa14a8 00007ff8 3c10ff30 00007ff8 ...:....0..<....
0x908febf8: 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000004 ................
0x908fec08: 000007a4 00000000 00000110 00000000 ................
0x908fec18: 00000001 00000000 3b73ce90 00007ff8 ..........s;....
0x908fec28: 00060ee4 00000000 7c5ecd50 00000226 ........P.^|&...
0x908fec38: 00000000 00000000 908fecf9 000000f7 ................
0x908fec48: 3b73db45 00007ff8 ffffffff 00000000 E.s;............
0x908fec58: 00000044 00000000 7c5ecd50 00000226 D.......P.^|&...
0x908fec68: 00000004 00000000 7c6092d0 00000226 ..........`|&...
0x908fec78: 00000018 00007ff8 00060ee4 00000000 ................
0x908fec88: 000002ab 00000000 7c6092d0 00000226 ..........`|&...
0x908fec98: 00000018 00000000 7c4608e0 00000226 ..........F|&...
0x908feca8: 00000018 00000000 00000044 000000f7 ........D.......
0x908fecb8: 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000 ................
0x908fecc8: 7c5f9570 00000226 00000020 00000000 p._|&... .......
0x908fecd8: 00000000 00000000 00000020 00000000 ........ .......
0x908fece8: 00000044 00007ff8 00000000 00000000 D...............
0x908fecf8: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x908fed08: fffffff0 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x908fed18: 000002e6 0000016b 0000049b 0000020e ....k...........
0x908fed28: 8ad8757b 00007ff8 00000110 00000000 {u..............
0x908fed38: 00060ee4 00000000 00000001 00000000 ................
0x908fed48: 00000001 00000000 908feeb8 000000f7 ................
0x908fed58: 8ad876f1 00007ff8 00000000 00000000 .v..............
0x908fed68: 00000001 000000f7 00000001 00000000 ................
0x908fed78: 00000001 00000000 908fedb0 000000f7 ................
0x908fed88: 908fedb8 000000f7 908ff040 000000f7 ........@.......
0x908fed98: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x908feda8: 80000012 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x908fedb8: 00000000 00000000 3b73ce90 00007ff8 ..........s;....
0x908fedc8: 8cc2f0c3 00007ff8 00000048 00000000 ........H.......
0x908fedd8: 00000001 00007ff8 00000000 00000000 ................
0x908fede8: 00000000 00000000 00000030 00000000 ........0.......
0x908fedf8: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ................
0x908fee08: 8ad8762a 00007ff8 00000000 00000000 *v..............
0x908fee18: 00000087 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x908fee28: 00000001 00000000 00060ee4 00000000 ................
0x908fee38: 8ad8790d 00007ff8 00000000 00000000 .y..............
0x908fee48: 00000110 00000000 7afa0e20 00000226 ........ ..z&...
0x908fee58: 00040efa 00000000 00040efa 00000000 ................
0x908fee68: 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000 ................
0x908fee78: 908fee80 000000f7 00000000 00000000 ................
0x908fee88: fffffffe ffffffff 00000000 00000000 ................
0x908fee98: 00000000 00000000 2541cce8 000085dd ..........A%....
0x908feea8: 8ad8ba42 00007ff8 80000012 00000000 B...............
0x908feeb8: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x908feec8: 00000110 00000000 00060ee4 00000000 ................
0x908feed8: 00040efa 00000000 00000110 00000000 ................
0x908feee8: 00000000 00000000 908ff250 000000f7 ........P.......
0x908feef8: 8add2269 00007ff8 00000000 00000000 i"..............
0x908fef08: 89cae074 00007ff8 00000000 00000000 t...............
0x908fef18: 00000000 00000000 00000001 0000c4a1 ................
0x908fef28: fffffffe ffffffff 80000012 00000000 ................
0x908fef38: 8ad8b85d 00007ff8 00000001 00000000 ]...............
0x908fef48: 00000000 00000000 908fefd8 000000f7 ................
0x908fef58: 8adfca7f 00007ff8 908feaa9 000000f7 ................
0x908fef68: 8ad8b6f7 00007ff8 00000004 00000000 ................
0x908fef78: 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000 ................
0x908fef88: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x908fef98: 00000000 80000012 00000000 00000000 ................
0x908fefa8: 00000000 00000000 b2e757e3 00000000 .........W......
0x908fefb8: 00000000 00000000 00000048 00000000 ........H.......
0x908fefc8: 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x908fefd8: 00000000 00000000 00000030 00000000 ........0.......
0x908fefe8: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ................
0x908feff8: 8ad8b6f7 00007ff8 00000000 00000000 ................
0x908ff008: 00000000 00000000 00000004 00000000 ................
0x908ff018: 1000b610 00000000 00000008 00000000 ................
0x908ff028: 7f04ab40 00007ff8 00050eea 00000000 @...............
0x908ff038: 00000000 00000000 8ccc0060 00007ff8 ........`.......
0x908ff048: 00000000 00000000 1000b610 00000000 ................
0x908ff058: 00000087 00000000 00050eea 00000000 ................
0x908ff068: 2541d2a8 000085dd 00000000 00000000 ..A%............
0x908ff078: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x908ff088: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x908ff098: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x908ff0a8: 8ad8b54c 00007ff8 00000008 00000000 L...............
0x908ff0b8: 8ccc0060 00007ff8 00060ee4 00000000 `...............
0x908ff0c8: 80000000 00000000 00040efa 00000000 ................
0x908ff0d8: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x908ff0e8: 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x908ff0f8: 00060ee4 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x908ff108: 8ada19c3 00007ff8 00000000 00000000 ................
0x908ff118: 00000000 00000000 00040efa 00000000 ................
0x908ff128: 908ff198 000000f7 8ccc0060 00007ff8 ........`.......
0x908ff138: 7af522c0 00000226 908ff1c8 000000f7 .".z&...........
0x908ff148: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x908ff158: 8ae031e0 00007ff8 8ccc0160 00007ff8 .1......`.......
0x908ff168: 8ccc3f94 00007ff8 00000000 00000000 .?..............
0x908ff178: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x908ff188: 00000000 00000000 908ff1c8 000000f7 ................
0x908ff198: 00000030 00000002 899c1164 00007ff8 0.......d.......
0x908ff1a8: 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000 ................
0x908ff1b8: 908ff1f8 000000f7 00000000 00000000 ................
0x908ff1c8: 7afa0e20 00000226 00000110 00000000 ..z&...........
0x908ff1d8: 00040efa 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x908ff1e8: 8ccc0060 00007ff8 8ccc01d0 00007ff8 `...............
0x908ff1f8: 8ad8ace8 00007ff8 00000000 00000000 ................
0x908ff208: 40000600 00000000 00060ee4 00000000 ...@............
0x908ff218: 00050eea 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x908ff228: 000002b1 00007ff8 00000000 000085dd ................
0x908ff238: 8ad99b00 00007ff8 00000000 00000226 ............&...
0x908ff248: 00000000 00000000 3c2af284 00007ff8 ..........*<....
0x908ff258: 00040efa 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x908ff268: 00000006 00000000 00060ee4 00000000 ................
0x908ff278: 3b73ce90 00007ff8 908ff390 000000f7 ..s;............
0x908ff288: 8ad9c311 00007ff8 7afa0e20 00000226 ........ ..z&...
0x908ff298: 3b73ce00 00007ff8 00040efa 00000000 ..s;............
0x908ff2a8: 7afa0e20 00000226 00000000 000000f7 ..z&...........
0x908ff2b8: 000000bb 00000000 000001bb 00007ff8 ................
0x908ff2c8: 000000ac 00000000 00060ee4 00000000 ................
0x908ff2d8: 000003f8 00000000 3acd0000 00007ff8 ...........:....
0x908ff2e8: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x908ff2f8: 00000000 00007ff8 40000600 00000000 ...........@....
0x908ff308: 00000000 00000000 00000000 0000000d ................
0x908ff318: 000003f8 000000ac ffff0001 00000000 ................
0x908ff328: 00010101 80c800cc 00000005 01350000 ..............5.
0x908ff338: 8cc400fa 00007ff8 00000000 00000000 ................
0x908ff348: 000001d6 000001b3 00000000 00000000 ................
0x908ff358: 00000006 00000006 1a0a24de 00000000 .........$......
0x908ff368: 40000600 00000000 000000bb 00000000 ...@............
0x908ff378: 0000000b 000001bb 00000003 00007ff8 ................
0x908ff388: 80000000 00007ff8 3c2af282 00007ff8 ..........*<....
0x908ffdf8: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x908ffe08: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x908fffb8: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x908fffc8: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x908fffd8: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x908fffe8: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
0x908ffff8: 00000000 00000000 ........

Module 1
C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\HydraVision\HydraDMH64.dll
Image Base: 0x10000000 Image Size: 0x00041000
File Size: 241664 File Time: 2013-12-06_155320
Version:
Company: AMD
Product: AMD HydraVision Desktop Manager
FileDesc: HydraDMH
FileVer: 4.0.66.0
ProdVer: 4.0.66.0


== [end of error.log] ==
```

Here is the output_log.txt:

```
Initialize engine version: 2017.4.0f1 (b5bd171ee9ba)
GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=1
Direct3D:
Version: Direct3D 11.0 [level 11.1]
Renderer: AMD Radeon R9 200 Series (ID=0x6810)
Vendor: ATI
VRAM: 4076 MB
Driver: 22.19.677.257
Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly
- Completed reload, in 0.044 seconds
Crash!!!
SymInit: Symbol-SearchPath: '.;D:\Dropbox\Divers\Programmation\Unity\Tuto\Crash Test;D:\Dropbox\Divers\Programmation\Unity\Tuto\Crash Test;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32;SRV*C:\websymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;', symOptions: 530, UserName: 'vdlmrc'
OS-Version: 10.0.16299 () 0x100-0x1
D:\Dropbox\Divers\Programmation\Unity\Tuto\Crash Test\Crash Test 64.exe:Crash Test 64.exe (00007FF761610000), size: 671744 (result: 0), SymType: 'PDB', PDB: '.\WindowsPlayer_x64_Master.pdb', fileVersion: 2017.4.0.48407
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll:ntdll.dll (00007FF88CC20000), size: 1966080 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.334
C:\Program Files (x86)\AVG\Antivirus\x64\aswhooka.dll:aswhooka.dll (00007FF8625B0000), size: 212992 (result: 0), SymType: '-nosymbols-', PDB: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\AVG\Antivirus\x64\aswhooka.dll', fileVersion: 18.2.3.24996
C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL:KERNEL32.DLL (00007FF88C540000), size: 712704 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll:KERNELBASE.dll (00007FF889C50000), size: 2514944 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.334
C:\WINDOWS\System32\ADVAPI32.dll:ADVAPI32.dll (00007FF88C460000), size: 659456 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\ADVAPI32.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.192
C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll:msvcrt.dll (00007FF88ABA0000), size: 643072 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll', fileVersion: 7.0.16299.125
C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll:sechost.dll (00007FF88AA80000), size: 372736 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll:RPCRT4.dll (00007FF88A950000), size: 1175552 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.309
D:\Dropbox\Divers\Programmation\Unity\Tuto\Crash Test\UnityPlayer.dll:UnityPlayer.dll (00007FF83ACD0000), size: 23048192 (result: 0), SymType: 'PDB', PDB: '.\UnityPlayer_Win32_x64.pdb', fileVersion: 2017.4.0.48407
C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll:USER32.dll (00007FF88AD80000), size: 1634304 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.125
C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll:win32u.dll (00007FF8899C0000), size: 131072 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll:GDI32.dll (00007FF88A920000), size: 163840 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll:gdi32full.dll (00007FF8890D0000), size: 1650688 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.98
C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll:msvcp_win.dll (00007FF889A30000), size: 634880 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.248
C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll:ucrtbase.dll (00007FF889AD0000), size: 1007616 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.248
C:\WINDOWS\System32\ole32.dll:eek:le32.dll (00007FF88C970000), size: 1347584 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\ole32.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.192
C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll:combase.dll (00007FF88A610000), size: 3178496 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll:bcryptPrimitives.dll (00007FF889BD0000), size: 466944 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.98
C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHLWAPI.dll:SHLWAPI.dll (00007FF88AB40000), size: 331776 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHLWAPI.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\System32\SETUPAPI.dll:SETUPAPI.dll (00007FF88A0F0000), size: 4513792 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\SETUPAPI.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.248
C:\WINDOWS\System32\cfgmgr32.dll:cfgmgr32.dll (00007FF8899E0000), size: 303104 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\cfgmgr32.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHELL32.dll:SHELL32.dll (00007FF88AF10000), size: 21192704 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHELL32.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.251
C:\WINDOWS\System32\shcore.dll:shcore.dll (00007FF88CAC0000), size: 679936 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\shcore.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\System32\windows.storage.dll:windows.storage.dll (00007FF889270000), size: 7630848 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\windows.storage.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.309
C:\WINDOWS\System32\kernel.appcore.dll:kernel.appcore.dll (00007FF888F90000), size: 69632 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\kernel.appcore.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\System32\powrprof.dll:powrprof.dll (00007FF888FD0000), size: 311296 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\powrprof.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\System32\profapi.dll:profapi.dll (00007FF888F70000), size: 110592 (result: 0), SymType: '-nosymbols-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\profapi.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WS2_32.dll:WS2_32.dll (00007FF88ACE0000), size: 442368 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\WS2_32.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\System32\OLEAUT32.dll:OLEAUT32.dll (00007FF88A540000), size: 806912 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\OLEAUT32.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\System32\IMM32.dll:IMM32.dll (00007FF88AD50000), size: 184320 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\IMM32.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\HID.DLL:HID.DLL (00007FF887D40000), size: 49152 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\HID.DLL', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll:VERSION.dll (00007FF883CA0000), size: 40960 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\OPENGL32.dll:OPENGL32.dll (00007FF849170000), size: 1171456 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\OPENGL32.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll:WINMM.dll (00007FF885210000), size: 143360 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DNSAPI.dll:DNSAPI.dll (00007FF8885D0000), size: 745472 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DNSAPI.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.334
C:\WINDOWS\System32\NSI.dll:NSI.dll (00007FF88C530000), size: 32768 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\NSI.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL:IPHLPAPI.DLL (00007FF888590000), size: 233472 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINHTTP.dll:WINHTTP.dll (00007FF883F20000), size: 909312 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINHTTP.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.334
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.DLL:CRYPTBASE.DLL (00007FF8889C0000), size: 45056 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.DLL', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\GLU32.dll:GLU32.dll (00007FF849140000), size: 180224 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\GLU32.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll:WINMMBASE.dll (00007FF8851A0000), size: 172032 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll:uxtheme.dll (00007FF887550000), size: 610304 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\HydraVision\HydraDMH64.dll:HydraDMH64.dll (0000000010000000), size: 266240 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\HydraVision\HydraDMH64.dll', fileVersion: 4.0.66.0
D:\Dropbox\Divers\Programmation\Unity\Tuto\Crash Test\Crash Test 64_Data\Mono\EmbedRuntime\mono.dll:mono.dll (00007FF849320000), size: 3010560 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'D:\Dropbox\Divers\Programmation\Unity\Tuto\Crash Test\Crash Test 64_Data\Mono\EmbedRuntime\mono.dll', fileVersion: 1.0.0.1
C:\WINDOWS\System32\PSAPI.DLL:pSAPI.DLL (00007FF88AA70000), size: 32768 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\PSAPI.DLL', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSWSOCK.dll:MSWSOCK.dll (00007FF888800000), size: 417792 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSWSOCK.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\System32\MSCTF.dll:MSCTF.dll (00007FF88C7A0000), size: 1470464 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\MSCTF.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.19
C:\WINDOWS\system32\dwmapi.dll:dwmapi.dll (00007FF887810000), size: 172032 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\dwmapi.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\d3d11.dll:d3d11.dll (00007FF886390000), size: 3022848 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\d3d11.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.248
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dxgi.dll:dxgi.dll (00007FF887DD0000), size: 716800 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dxgi.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.98
C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\c0318486.inf_amd64_11ba0b4b7cc81d52\aticfx64.dll:aticfx64.dll (00007FF8828F0000), size: 1941504 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\c0318486.inf_amd64_11ba0b4b7cc81d52\aticfx64.dll', fileVersion: 22.19.677.257
C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\c0318486.inf_amd64_11ba0b4b7cc81d52\atiuxp64.dll:atiuxp64.dll (00007FF8828B0000), size: 229376 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\c0318486.inf_amd64_11ba0b4b7cc81d52\atiuxp64.dll', fileVersion: 22.19.677.257
C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\c0318486.inf_amd64_11ba0b4b7cc81d52\atidxx64.dll:atidxx64.dll (00007FF87FF20000), size: 15163392 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\c0318486.inf_amd64_11ba0b4b7cc81d52\atidxx64.dll', fileVersion: 22.19.677.257
C:\WINDOWS\System32\clbcatq.dll:clbcatq.dll (00007FF88AC40000), size: 647168 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\clbcatq.dll', fileVersion: 2001.12.10941.16384
C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem\wbemprox.dll:wbemprox.dll (00007FF877070000), size: 61440 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem\wbemprox.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\wbemcomn.dll:wbemcomn.dll (00007FF8792F0000), size: 528384 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\wbemcomn.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\bcrypt.dll:bcrypt.dll (00007FF888AD0000), size: 151552 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\bcrypt.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.125
C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem\wbemsvc.dll:wbemsvc.dll (00007FF878480000), size: 81920 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem\wbemsvc.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem\fastprox.dll:fastprox.dll (00007FF876550000), size: 983040 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem\fastprox.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\System32\MMDevApi.dll:MMDevApi.dll (00007FF881510000), size: 454656 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\MMDevApi.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\System32\DEVOBJ.dll:DEVOBJ.dll (00007FF888D80000), size: 159744 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\DEVOBJ.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\System32\PROPSYS.dll:pROPSYS.dll (00007FF884A50000), size: 1773568 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\PROPSYS.dll', fileVersion: 7.0.16299.334
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\wdmaud.drv:wdmaud.drv (00007FF871510000), size: 270336 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\wdmaud.drv', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ksuser.dll:ksuser.dll (00007FF883D70000), size: 36864 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ksuser.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\AVRT.dll:AVRT.dll (00007FF883EF0000), size: 40960 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\AVRT.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\AUDIOSES.DLL:AUDIOSES.DLL (00007FF87B8E0000), size: 1187840 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\AUDIOSES.DLL', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.248
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\wintypes.dll:wintypes.dll (00007FF884D50000), size: 1269760 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\wintypes.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\msacm32.drv:msacm32.drv (00007FF881AF0000), size: 49152 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\msacm32.drv', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSACM32.dll:MSACM32.dll (00007FF8714F0000), size: 114688 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSACM32.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\midimap.dll:midimap.dll (00007FF87E030000), size: 40960 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\midimap.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.16299.334_none_15cad2e69362ed51\comctl32.dll:comctl32.dll (00007FF87F040000), size: 2527232 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.16299.334_none_15cad2e69362ed51\comctl32.dll', fileVersion: 6.10.16299.334
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\TextInputFramework.dll:TextInputFramework.dll (00007FF880DA0000), size: 622592 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\TextInputFramework.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.334
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CoreUIComponents.dll:CoreUIComponents.dll (00007FF8835B0000), size: 3072000 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CoreUIComponents.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CoreMessaging.dll:CoreMessaging.dll (00007FF886C40000), size: 901120 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CoreMessaging.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.192
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntmarta.dll:ntmarta.dll (00007FF8880A0000), size: 200704 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntmarta.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll:dbghelp.dll (00007FF877550000), size: 1867776 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.15
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SspiCli.dll:SspiCli.dll (00007FF888EA0000), size: 196608 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SspiCli.dll', fileVersion: 10.0.16299.192

========== OUTPUTING STACK TRACE ==================

0x00007FF83B7394A1 (UnityPlayer) FillResolutionsList
0x00007FF83B73DB45 (UnityPlayer) screenSelDialogProc
0x00007FF88AD876F1 (USER32) SetWindowTextW
0x00007FF88AD8790D (USER32) SetWindowTextW
0x00007FF88ADD2269 (USER32) UnpackDDElParam
0x00007FF88AD8B85D (USER32) CallWindowProcW
0x00007FF88AD8B54C (USER32) CallWindowProcW
0x00007FF88ADA19C3 (USER32) GetTopWindow
0x00007FF88CCC3F94 (ntdll) KiUserCallbackDispatcher
0x00007FF8899C1164 (win32u) NtUserMessageCall
0x00007FF88AD8ACE8 (USER32) SendMessageW
0x00007FF88AD9C311 (USER32) CreateWindowInBandEx
0x00007FF88ADAB6F4 (USER32) DialogBoxIndirectParamAorW
0x00007FF88ADAB5D2 (USER32) DialogBoxIndirectParamAorW
0x00007FF88ADC9EB7 (USER32) DialogBoxParamA
0x00007FF83B7375AC (UnityPlayer) DisplayScreenSelectorIfNecessary
0x00007FF83B741A75 (UnityPlayer) UnityMainImpl
0x00007FF83B74231B (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FF7616113EE (Crash Test 64) __scrt_common_main_seh
0x00007FF88C551FE4 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FF88CC8F061 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart

========== END OF STACKTRACE ===========

**** Crash! ****
```

Comment: It might be a better option for you to report this to Unity as a bug and get a response from them. A C# script error should not crash your game like this. It looks like it is either a bug in Unity or an issue with your machine.

Comment: You could try (1) running it on a different machine (2) making a development build and see if it still happens.

Comment: I think your best lead is stack trace that starts from (UnityPlayer) DisplayScreenSelectorIfNecessary and crashes to (UnityPlayer) FillResolutionsList. Therefore I would try reproducing the error with different monitor/VR/graphics setup.

Comment: Why is the user address space 134 terabytes? That doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: 64-bit process running in 64-bit Win10 can have 128TB user mode virtual address space. I believe 128TB == 2^47 B == 134217728*1024*1024 B

Comment: Thanks all. So far I submitted a bug report to Unity. It seems someone is looking into it since yesterday morning. Hopefully, I'll get a solution soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I had the solution to this bug from a member of the Unity team, on their forum.
This is a known bug from Unity. This bug has been fixed on some versions of Unity. The Unity guy told me this bug was fixed on versions 2018.1.0b11, 2017.4.1f1, 2017.2.2p2, 2017.1.3p3, 5.6.5p3.

I tried building my game on Unity 2017.2.2p2 and running the build. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a run-in with the same error on a steam game. (ShadowRun Returns btw) There is one dll file that the output_log.txt marks with -nosymbols- instead of -exported-, and it is called profapi.dll. I did a quick google search and saw that it was not necessary for Windows, so as a test I changed the extention to .disabled. (Nothing special about the extension, I just wanted to make sure I could recover it if needed.) After doing that, the game launched just fine. Other than that, there was a common bug with antivirus' causing the problem as well.